# ReactNative MongoDB default app client has not yet been initialized/set

Tags: mongodb, react-native, mongodb-stitch

I'm new to ReactNative, and I am trying to connect MongoDB Atlas to my RN app. I'm getting an error saying `default app client has not yet been initialized/set` even though I'm calling the `Stitch.initializeDefaultAppClient(MONGODB_APP_CLIENT)` method.

I followed this tutorial: https://levelup.gitconnected.com/react-native-mongodb-stitch-building-a-crud-application-without-a-server-3e4ae0b34d67

In App.js:

```
import { Stitch, AnonymousCredential } from "mongodb-stitch-react-native-sdk";
...
_loadClient() {
    Stitch.initializeDefaultAppClient(MONGODB_APP_CLIENT).then(client => {
      this.setState({ client });
      this.state.client.auth
        .loginWithCredential(new AnonymousCredential())
        .then(user => {
          console.log(`Successfully logged in as user ${user.id}`);
          this.setState({ currentUserId: user.id });
          this.setState({ currentUserId: client.auth.user.id });
        })
        .catch(err => {
          console.log(`Failed to log in anonymously: ${err}`);
          this.setState({ currentUserId: undefined });
        });
    });
  }
}
...
```

In Contacts.js:

```
import { Stitch, RemoteMongoClient } from "mongodb-stitch-react-native-sdk";
..
constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
          isLoading: true,
          users: []
        };

        this._loadClient = this._loadClient.bind(this);
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        this._loadClient();
    }

_loadClient() {
        const stitchAppClient = Stitch.defaultAppClient;
        const mongoClient = stitchAppClient.getServiceClient(
          RemoteMongoClient.factory,
          "mongodb-atlas"
        );
        const db = mongoClient.db("dbapp");
        const users = db.collection("users");
        users
          .find({ status: "new" }, { sort: { date: -1 } })
          .asArray()
          .then(docs => {
            this.setState({ users });
          })
          .catch(err => {
            console.warn(err);
          });
    }
...
```

Above, I'm sharing the code that is necessary for this to work. I have it all in my code, and even though I initialized the app client, I'm still getting an error. Would love all the help I can get here!

Full error message:

```
Error: default app client has not yet been initialized/set

This error is located at:
    in Contacts (at SceneView.js:9)
    in SceneView (at StackViewLayout.tsx:910)
    in RCTView (at View.js:45)
    in View (at createAnimatedComponent.js:151)
    in AnimatedComponent (at StackViewCard.tsx:106)
    in RCTView (at View.js:45)
    in View (at createAnimatedComponent.js:151)
    in AnimatedComponent (at screens.native.js:71)
    in Screen (at StackViewCard.tsx:93)
    in Card (at createPointerEventsContainer.tsx:95)
    in Container (at StackViewLayout.tsx:985)
    in RCTView (at View.js:45)
    in View (at screens.native.js:101)
    in ScreenContainer (at StackViewLayout.tsx:394)
    in RCTView (at View.js:45)
    in View (at createAnimatedComponent.js:151)
    in AnimatedComponent (at StackViewLayout.tsx:384)
    in PanGestureHandler (at StackViewLayout.tsx:377)
    in StackViewLayout (at withOrientation.js:30)
    in withOrientation (at StackView.tsx:104)
    in RCTView (at View.js:45)
    in View (at Transitioner.tsx:267)
    in Transitioner (at StackView.tsx:41)
    in StackView (at createNavigator.js:81)
    in Navigator (at createKeyboardAwareNavigator.js:12)
    in KeyboardAwareNavigator (at SceneView.js:9)
    in SceneView (at createTabNavigator.js:39)
    in RCTView (at View.js:45)
    in View (at ResourceSavingScene.js:37)
    in RCTView (at View.js:45)
    in View (at ResourceSavingScene.js:26)
    in ResourceSavingScene (at createBottomTabNavigator.js:120)
    in RCTView (at View.js:45)
    in View (at screens.native.js:101)
    in ScreenContainer (at createBottomTabNavigator.js:110)
    in RCTView (at View.js:45)
    in View (at createBottomTabNavigator.js:109)
    in TabNavigationView (at createTabNavigator.js:197)
    in NavigationView (at createNavigator.js:81)
    in Navigator (at SceneView.js:9)
    in SceneView (at SwitchView.js:12)
    in SwitchView (at createNavigator.js:81)
    in Navigator (at createAppContainer.js:430)
    in NavigationContainer (at App.js:38)
    in RCTView (at View.js:45)
    in View (at App.js:36)
    in App (at withExpoRoot.js:20)
    in RootErrorBoundary (at withExpoRoot.js:19)
    in ExpoRootComponent (at renderApplication.js:35)
    in RCTView (at View.js:45)
    in View (at AppContainer.js:98)
    in RCTView (at View.js:45)
    in View (at AppContainer.js:115)
    in AppContainer (at renderApplication.js:34)

Function.get [as defaultAppClient]
    106aa394-9652-42d9-8b6b-cda0fd593b63:183243:17
Contacts._loadClient
    106aa394-9652-42d9-8b6b-cda0fd593b63:152692:67
Contacts.proxiedMethod
    106aa394-9652-42d9-8b6b-cda0fd593b63:47391:32
Contacts.componentDidMount
    106aa394-9652-42d9-8b6b-cda0fd593b63:152685:14
Contacts.proxiedComponentDidMount
    106aa394-9652-42d9-8b6b-cda0fd593b63:47404:42
commitLifeCycles
    106aa394-9652-42d9-8b6b-cda0fd593b63:21888:28
commitAllLifeCycles
    106aa394-9652-42d9-8b6b-cda0fd593b63:23239:13
Object.invokeGuardedCallbackImpl
    106aa394-9652-42d9-8b6b-cda0fd593b63:11985:16
invokeGuardedCallback
    106aa394-9652-42d9-8b6b-cda0fd593b63:12076:37
commitRoot
    106aa394-9652-42d9-8b6b-cda0fd593b63:23433:13
```

**As an update**, this error is randomly occurring, and randomly not occurring. One minute it loads my data, and next time I save the file (and the app reloads), I get the error again. Reloading a bunch of times ends up fixing it. But then, of course, it'll happen again.

Comment: Are you actually using “Name” or is that a placeholder? 
It should be Stitch.initialzieDefaultAppClient(“<your-client-app-id>”)

Comment: it's a placeholder, so the name isnt public online. i'm now using an environment variable, which i'll update this post with

Comment: If it happens sometimes and not others it sounds like a race condition. Is the initializing of the client sync or async? Do you the client anywhere else in your code (not posted) it could be that it’s still initializing the client then. I’d suggest placing breakpoints and checking to make sure they are always hit in the proper order l

Comment: the client is ONLY initialized in App.js, and simply loads the client in Contacts.js

Comment: The code snippet provided doesn’t show where _loadClient is being called in App.Js. There seems to be some timing issue/race that’s occurring which means understanding exactly when everything is being called is helpful.is contacts.js initialized in App.Js? If so, when? Before or after the App.Js calls _loadClient etc etc. Breakpoints to make sure the flow is proper seems like a good first check. If you place a breakpoint in _loadClient in App.JS and in Contacts.js _loadClient, what gets called firs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following changes seem to have worked:

App.js:

```
_loadClient() {
    Stitch.initializeDefaultAppClient(MONGODB_APP_CLIENT)
    .then(client => {
      client.auth
        .loginWithCredential(new AnonymousCredential())
        .then(user => {
          console.log(`Successfully logged in as user ${user.id}`);
          this.setState({
            currentUserId: user.id,
            currentUserId: client.auth.user.id,
            client,
          });
        })
        .catch(err => {
          console.log(`Failed to log in anonymously: ${err}`);
          this.setState({
            currentUserId: undefined,
            client,
          });
        });
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.error(err)
    });
  }
```

Contacts.js:

```
_loadClient() {
        if (Stitch.hasAppClient(MONGODB_APP_CLIENT)) {
          const app = Stitch.getAppClient(MONGODB_APP_CLIENT);
          this._loadData(app);
        } else {
          Stitch.initializeAppClient(MONGODB_APP_CLIENT)
          .then(app => this._loadData(app))
          .catch(err => console.error(err));
        }
    }
_loadData(appClient) {
      const mongoClient = appClient.getServiceClient(
          RemoteMongoClient.factory,
          "mongodb-atlas"
        );
        const db = mongoClient.db("sidapp");
        const users = db.collection("users");
        users
          .find({ type: 2 })
          .asArray()
          .then(users => {
            this.setState({ users });
          })
          .catch(err => {
            console.warn(err);
          });
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I encountered this error as well. Solved it by replacing 
`const stitchAppClient = Stitch.defaultAppClient;` in Contacts.js to the following:

```
Stitch.initializeDefaultAppClient(MONGODB_APP_CLIENT).then(client => {
      const mongoClient = stitchAppClient.getServiceClient(
          RemoteMongoClient.factory,
          "mongodb-atlas"
        );

      client.auth
        .loginWithCredential(new AnonymousCredential())
        .then(user => {
           // Your code to connect to the database and collection
         });
}
```

I'm not sure if there's a bug which cause that error. I'm pretty new to React Native as well.

Hope this will help as I referenced this workaround off MongoDB's blog for MongoDB Stitch React Native SDK

Comment: I already did this in `App.js`, it's supposed to initialize mongo there. I tried this anyways, and I get errors that say I can only initialize it once. How can I write a Promise that only loads `users` from the collection only once `App.js` is done initializing mongo?

Comment: Maybe you can try chaining promises? I'm not too sure about promises. I'm quite new to Javascript as well. Sorry that I can't help much :(

Comment: Thanks for trying, definitely appreciated